# Access Runtime - Trusting Application?

Tags: ms-access, runtime

I developed an Access application in Access 2016 32 bit.  I have the front end and back end split, and am working to make this app shared on a network.  Some of the users may not have access, so I am testing access runtime. I installed runtime on 1 machine, and when I launch the front end, either with an accdr extension or with the /runtime switch, I get a warning that the app could be dangerous. It says "A potential security concern has been identified.

Warning: It is not possible to determine that this content came from a trustworthy source. You should leave this content disabled unless the content provides critical functionality and you trust its source.

The file might contain unsafe content that could harm your computer. Do you want to open this file or cancel the operation?"

I click to open the app. Then when I click any button on the main menu, to open a form, I get a generic run-time error - "Execution of this application has stopped due to a run-time error. The application cant continue and will be shut down."

I tried saving the front end as a sign and package, but I can't seem to combine that with running it in run-time, unless I'm just not understanding how all this works.

How can I make this location on the network trusted on the computer, make the file trusted, or whatever I need to do, so that this app can run in run-time for users who don't have Access installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you copied the front-end to the local hard drive of the machine that has the Access Runtime installed?

Comment: Study my article: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html?preview=X8LitkMCd/Y%3D).

Comment: Yes, @Gord. I have an external drive, with folders containing the frontend and the backend.

Comment: @Gustav, Your solution looks really good, but it may be a bit more than will make sense or be needed for my challenge.  This is a short-term need, with a handful of people. I was researching the issue of the registry entry, and plan to test just adding the registry, and seeing if that allows the run-time to work. We'll see if that does it. If not, I'll look into your solution more. I don't have VS at home though, so it will be notepad++.

Comment: Have a look at the script that @Gustav wrote. It handles the `Trusted Locations` issue, which could very well be what's tripping you up.

Comment: I have the reg key, which really only needs to be run once, so I don't want to run that every time, if I don't have to. Then I already use a bat file.  Mine just handles it a little differently:

del "%appdata%\XYZAppFE.accdr"
xcopy /D /Y "\\SharedDrive\AppPath\Front\XYZAppFE.accdr" "%appdata%"
Start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\MSACCESS.EXE" "%appdata%\XYZAppFE.accdr"

Comment: I got this working. Adding the reg key did the trick After that, I am able to run the application without a problem. Thanks!